# Spring boot JPA deserialization problem when retrieving ID from other entity

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa

I'm creating a web program to map stores occupation levels with spring boot, tomcat and JPA.
I've already created the member model/service/controller and it's working properly when I try to update it, create it, delete it or get info from it.

Stores however are not being created as well, when I create a store with the ownerId I get an error message saying:

**Error message**

*[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.project.so2.models.Member` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.project.so2.models.Member` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.project.so2.models.Store["owner_id"])]*

I've tried to look up similar problems but I haven't seen any applicable solution.

**Models**

*Stores*

```
@Entity(name = "Store")
@Table(name = "store")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "store_id")
public class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "store_id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    //many stores to one owner
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Member owner_id;
    
    //one store to many occupation level
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Occupation> store_occupation;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "store")
    private Location location;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "square_footage")
    private String square_footage;

    public Store() {
    }
```

*Members*

```
@Entity(name = "Member")
@Table(name = "member")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "member_id")
public class Member {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "member_id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")    
    private Role role;//customer|admin|store_owner
    
    @Column(name = "mail", unique = true)
    private String mail;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner_id")
    private List<Store> stores;
    
    
    
    /**
     * REALM to store passwords
     */
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updateAt;
```

**Store controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/store")
@ControllerAdvice()
@CrossOrigin
public class StoreController {
    @Autowired
    private StoreService storeservice;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> createStore(@RequestBody Store store) {
        try {
            this.storeservice.saveStore(store);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**Store Service**

```
@Service
public class StoreService {
    
    @Autowired
    private StoreRepository storeRepository;//

    public void saveStore(Store store) {
        this.storeRepository.save(store); 
    }
```

**Request Payload:**

```
{
    "name": "Pingo Azedo",
    "square_footage": "25m^2",
    "owner_id":{
        "member_id": "1"
    }
}
```

I honestly don't understand the problem and don't get how to fix it. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you post the whole class store and members?

Comment: I just did, only left out the getters and setters @Hưng Chu

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Just did so @YohanAloka

Comment: this can be an issue with the request payload, can you post request payload too?

Comment: @YohanAloka I've inserted it now too

Comment: I don't see anything that is mapping to the key 'user_id'  from your payload

Comment: @Sid you're right, I've changed it to member_id but the problem still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re trying to deserialize member from json, but jackson do not know how to fill in this member with just “member_id”, and the error is clearly say so “no constructer with String is found”. So, in order to get the member id, you need to add new class request dto, something like:

```
String name;
String footage;
Long owner_id;
```

Use your new class in your controller, now with owner_id, use repository to find it in your db, then set it to your store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property names in the payload, not column names. Change your request payload like below,

```
{
  "name": "Pingo Azedo",
  "square_footage": "25m^2",
  "owner_id":{
       "id" : 1
    }
}
```